# Android -- Kill Multiple Previous Activites When Launching a New One

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-intent

So, I konw that it is possible to kill the current activity and launch a new activity simply by doing the following:

```
//Presumably called from class A
Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
startActivity(i);
A.this.finish();
```

I realize that there is some overly-verbose code in there, I just want to be thorough. So if we assume that this is called from some Activity A, then we know that A will finish and B will start and when you press the back button in B, you will be taken to the Activity that was running prior to Activity A.

My question is, can this be taken one level further? For example, how would I acheive the following?

```
//From class A
Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
startActivity(i);


//from class B
Intent i = new Intent(B.this, C.class);
startActivity(i);
A.this.finish(); //something equivalent
B.this.finish();
```

Thank you in advance for any insight! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why I do believe you are looking for the `Intent` flag [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP).

This will clear the back-stack of all activities through the last instance of the target activity class (or all if the new activity has never been called).

Comment: This works perfect for what I was working on! Just wish you could have a little more control over which activities to erase from the "history." Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is helpful to you (it doesn't address your question specifically) but usually people want to do this because they have circular code that results in the same activity being launched a bunch of times over and over.  You can designate an activity as (basically) a singleton, so that no matter how many times you launch it, it's always launching the same one... just add `android:launchMode= "singleTask"` in your manifest for that activity.
My apologies in advance if this is not helpful to your cause :)